# Cell set equal to anchored ranges returns only one value in that range....why?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've used this formula before but I don't really understand why it gives the result as such. I understand how anchors work ($A anchors the COLUMN and $2 anchors the ROW). However I'm still trying to understand if the cell is equal to a range, how come it displays the same number? In other words, the range B2:B6 all equal $A$2:$A

Why does this happen?

Does the cell evaluate the value of $A$2:$A(current row)? If so, shouldn't this yield a range rather than one specific number?

Thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is because you are using a non-array function and therefore only single values will be passed. The same will happen if you use `A2:A`. Only one value (the first one corresponding to 10) will be displayed.

If you want to reference a range in a cell you should use an array formula to be able to populate all the cells of that range. You can easily achieve this by using [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA($A$2:$A)
```

Comment: This answer was so clear a 2 year old could understand. Thank you so much. My constant wondering is over.

Comment: Dont worry, it is not as intuitive as one would think. Glad this solved your questions. Please consider accepting my answer (the green tick) if it solved your doubts :D